# AWS Lambda python function sending multiple SNS messages

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have Python 3.6 in an AWS Lambda function and it's processing each item multiple times rather than just once and I can't figure out why. It's checking for a specific tag value and sending an email through SNS when that value is met but rather than getting one email alerts I get 5 or more.

The relevant code is below and I have x out the account numbers.

```
aws_account_numbers = {xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx,xxxxxxxxxxx}


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    mdy = today_string = today.strftime('%m/%d/%y')

    for name, acctnum in aws_account_numbers.items():
        roleArn = "arn:aws:iam::%s:role/EOTSS-Monitor-Tags-expenddate" % acctnum
        stsClient = boto3.client('sts')
        sts_response = stsClient.assume_role(RoleArn=roleArn,RoleSessionName='AssumeCrossAccountRole', DurationSeconds=1800)
        ec2 = boto3.resource(service_name='ec2',region_name=region,aws_access_key_id = sts_response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
            aws_secret_access_key = sts_response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'], aws_session_token = sts_response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])

        for instance in ec2.instances.all():
            if instance.tags is None:
                continue
            for tag in instance.tags:
                if tag['Key'] == 'expenddate':
                    expiredInstances=[]
                    if (tag['Value']) <= mdy:
                        sns_client.publish(
                            TopicArn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:EOTSS-Monitor-Tag-Exceptions-Temp',
                            Subject = '!!!! Tag Exception has Expired.',
                            Message = str("The tag exception for instance %s has expired in account %s" % (instance.id,acctnum)))
                else:
                    print ("end")
    return "sucess"
```

Comment: What's expected behaviour if you have multiple instances in multiple accounts which satisfies the reqiurement?

Comment: What triggers your Lambda execution? An event? It is scheduled to run somewhere? Do you run it manually?

Comment: John - There are multiple instances in multiple accounts which may satisfy the tag value. Some days there are none other days there are multiple instances where the tag meets that criteria.

Comment: This is triggered at 2 AM EST each day by a CloudWatch rule. The interesting thing I found is that while testing I have switched the SNS Topic so that during my testing I would not be sending email to the whole team. I switch the SNS Topic to one that only notifies me. When I do that I only get a single email alert for each instance rather than 4 alerts for each I was getting with the other SNS topic.

Answer (score 0):

You should add additional debug code to confirm that the `publish()` command is being called multiple times.

For example:

```py
        for instance in ec2.instances.all():
            if instance.tags is None:
                continue
            for tag in instance.tags:
                print('Checking instance: ', instance.id)   # <-- Added
                if tag['Key'] == 'expenddate':
                    expiredInstances=[]
                    if (tag['Value']) <= mdy:
                        print('Sending publish message')    # <-- Added
                        sns_client.publish(
                            TopicArn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxx:EOTSS-Monitor-Tag-Exceptions-Temp',
                            Subject = '!!!! Tag Exception has Expired.',
                            Message = str("The tag exception for instance %s has expired in account %s" % (instance.id,acctnum)))
```

This will help you determine whether the code is sending multiple messages, or whether Amazon SNS is sending one message multiple times.

By the way, I could see where `region` was defined in your code and I couldn't see `expiredInstances` being used.

Comment: It seemed to be the SNS topic that was causing the issue. I deleted the SNS topic and recreated it with a slightly different name then pointed my Lambda function to that and for a few days now I am only getting a single email alert per instance where the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to be the SNS topic that was causing the issue. I deleted the SNS topic and recreated it with a slightly different name then pointed my Lambda function to that and for a few days now I am only getting a single email alert per instance where the condition is met.